Detecting array message
I found an old PC back from 2005. Tried to boot it up but it gave a message "Detecting array". Also tried dissabling SATA controller in BIOS but then a simple white line was blinking on the screen. Took the PC to a repair master and the master said "Your PC is dead." I have already reconnected the CMOS battery.. but still it wont work. Maybe you guys know how to fix that message?
Biostar MCP6PB M2+ (motherboard)

I wonder if this would be a better fit for retrocomputing.stackexchange.com
